# How to get data (question details) of a specific Stack Exchange site?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, data-explorer, data-dump

I am working on a data science project for which I need data (questions and corresponding tags) of a specific Stack Exchange site, [Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com) for example. From this [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/15/you-can-now-play-with-stack-overflow-data-on-googles-bigquery/) we know that SE data is publicly available, but I am not able to find a method to get data of a specific SE site.

The things I've checked:

- I've checked the table structure of questions [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/) in the `posts_questions` table.
- I've checked the dataset [here](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange) after downloading.

Did I miss anything?

The only thing which I can think of is writing a query and use it in [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/3160/jon-skeet-comparison). Is it correct? If yes, then how, as we don't have questions and site relations in any of the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each site has its own file in the data dump; the link for Academia is https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/academia.stackexchange.com.7z

As for SEDE, the query generally<sup>*</sup> operates on a single database, and each Stack Exchange site has its own database. An existing query can be run on another database with the 'Switch sites' field at the bottom of the page; for new queries, the Compose Query button has a site switcher as well:

[image]

AFAIK, Google BigQuery only hosts Stack Overflow data, and not the other sites in the network. So that is not an option for you.

<sup>*</sup><sub>: it's possible to write queries which operate over multiple/all databases/sites, e.g. [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/508589/better-template-for-multi-db-queries)</sub>

Comment: So for sites other than SO we've to use data dumps only??

Comment: No, SEDE works as well. The structure (i.e the data model) of the data is the same for all options, though.

Comment: Ok. Do data dumps contain all data till date or are they updated regularly? If regularly, how regularly?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-dump/info and https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq

Comment: For future reference, complete description of data-dump : [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/01/23/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/)