# Having difficulty listing my comments on Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm having difficulty listing my comments on Stack Exchange Data Explorer. I'm not experienced with it.

I tried this query, and it didn't list anything. 42672 is my id on SuperUser.

```
SELECT
  Id AS [Comment Link],
  Text
FROM Comments
where UserId=42672
```

Comment: @RobertLongson  I can't see an option to select a site to run it on?  so I just assumed it'd do superuser given my superuser id.. but it's not showing anything. Where is the option to select a site eg superuser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get data (question details) of a specific Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305128/how-to-get-data-question-details-of-a-specific-stack-exchange-site)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select the site you're running the query against. Start typing super in the input box and it will offer the site as a dropdown.

[image: site selection]

You might also find eventually that ordering the results helps, you can more easily compare the results against your profile.

```
SELECT
  Id AS [Comment Link],
  Text
FROM Comments
where UserId=42672
order by CreationDate desc
```